# Is there any way to pass not serializable arguments between Activity?

Tags: java, android, serialization

Is there any way to pass not serializable data between Activity in Android?
For example, how can i pass to an Intent this class if I can't serialize FieldForSomeReasonNotSerializable (like Bitmap, LatLng by Google, TextView):

```
class MyClass implements java.io.Serializable{
       String s = "serializable";
       FieldForSomeReasonNotSerializable field=new FieldForSomeReasonNotSerializable();
}
```

Comment: you should be passing a bitmap via an intent you should save that bitmap to disk then pass the file url for that bitmap. You also should not be passing a `View` in an intent

Comment: I know, it was just an example..
What about LatLng.class?

Comment: LatLng implements parcelable so you can already pass that in an intent

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Parcelable instead of Serializable. From android Studio the wizard (red bulb) will help you to implement the Parcelable interface. Just have click on Implements methods, and then in the class name with the same Red bulb add parcelable implementation

public class CategoryDTO implements Parcelable {

```
@PrimaryKey
private String id;

/**
 * Category Name
 */
private String name;

/**
 * Category Color
 */
private String color;


public CategoryDTO() {

}

public CategoryDTO(String id, String name, String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.id = id;
}

protected CategoryDTO(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    color = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();

}

public static final Creator<CategoryDTO> CREATOR = new Creator<CategoryDTO>() {
    @Override
    public CategoryDTO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CategoryDTO(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryDTO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CategoryDTO[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Thank you! It's very interesting Parcelablizatio(?), now i'm reading about that in java documentation..